# Problema para mostrar Categorías y los Productos debajo de cada Categoría

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy tratando de listar los productos agrupados por categorías, una especie de carta de platos dinámica. Tengo una tabla que almacena las categorías y otra que almacena los platos, en la última tabla hay un campo que relaciona con la tabla de categorías. En la vista, logro hacer que los nombres de las categorías se visualicen, pero los productos no, en el Modelo he revisado las consultas y todas devuelven resultados, incluso desde el JS, mostrando con console.log() los registros en formato JSON se visualizan, pero debajo de cada categoría no muestra nada.

Les paso la función de JS que se supone debe imprimir los nombres de las categorías y los platos debajo de ellas.

```
function llenarCategoriasPlatos() {

   var ajaxUrl = base_url + "Comidas/getCatPlatos";

   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: ajaxUrl,
       success: function(response) {
           var objData = JSON.parse(response);

           if (objData.status) {
               let catPlatos = '';
               let dPlatos = '';
               var urlPlatos = '';

               $('.content-carta').html('');

               for (let i = 0; i < objData.data.length; i++) {
                   $('.content-carta').append('<div class="row">' + 
                                               '<div class="col-md-12">' + 
                                                   '<h3><i class="fas fa-utensils"></i> ' + objData.data[i]["nombre"] + '</h3>' +  
                                                   '<div class="line"></div>' + 
                                               '</div>' + 
                                              '</div>');

                   urlPlatos = base_url + 'Comidas/getPlatos/' + objData.data[i]["codigo"];

                   $.ajax({
                       url: urlPlatos,
                       success: function(responseIn) {
                           var objDataPla = JSON.parse(responseIn);

                           if (objDataPla.status) {
                               $('.content-carta').append('Aquí se tiene que visualizar la lista de platos.');
                           }
                       }
                   });
               }
           }
       }
   });
 }
```

Donde se tiene que visualizar la lista de platos no sale nada y cuando le hago un console.log(responseIn) si me muestra los platos en consola y así coloque cualquier texto para imprimir ahí no me sale, le pongo el else a objDataIn.status y tampoco me muestra nada.

Que cosa podría estar mal en esa función?

Gracias de antemano gente sabia.

Comment: ¿Has probado en lugar de mandar un texto cualquiera enviar un tag válido, como un parrafo? ¿Es posible que puedas colocar un ejemplo reproducible usando arreglos llenos por defecto sin el API?

Comment: Si he hecho eso, he puesto un texto dentro de <p></p> tampoco sale nada